Using YOLO to Detect Objects from Specific Directional Images Only
I am working on an object detection task using YOLOv, where I have a dataset containing both front-facing and side-facing images of the same object. My goal is to train the model to detect only the front-facing images and ignore or differentiate side-facing images during detection.
I attempted to treat side-facing images as negative samples for training, but the results were unsatisfactory.
Could anyone suggest a more effective approach to solve this problem? Specifically, I need a method to ensure that side-facing images are either not detected at all or are distinguishable from the front-facing ones.
